# Groovy neo4j batch import

Tags: groovy, neo4j

I am using this script http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/flexible-neo4j-batch-import-with-groovy/ to import csv file to neo4j. The file is quite large: around 60 million lines. I allocated 30GB memory for properties, 30GB for nodes and 30GB for the rest. However, the importer gets stuck at 49 million lines. Is this the memory issue?

The output looks like this

48800000 lines processed in x seconds
48900000 lines processed in y seconds
and then it stops processing and is not moving.

Comment: what is "stuck"?  error, exception, nothing happens, 100% cpu, swapping, ...?

Comment: nothing happens. I will update the question now

Comment: is your db server doing all the work then?  flushing all batch informations or GCing the hell out of it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I am not a database person. I am using the code provided on github and adapted it to my needs in terms of properties and node indexing. Is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss relationships? **Those are the most crucial**
And I forgot one in the original example, which is the

`neostore.relgroupstore.db=10MB`

15 bytes per node
38 bytes per relationship
42 bytes per 4 properties

And do you have actually 128GB of RAM? To accomodate for the memory mapping?

What OS are you using?

Oh and at the end it stops for quite a long time to create the indexes and constraints, that might be the case.

You can add an output before that.

Comment: I am on Linux. My current machine has more than 100GB RAM, yes. I did add relationships after reading your post. It took around 20 minutes to index 45 million nodes this time.